# Custom ObjectChoiceField for touch screen

Tags: blackberry, combobox, width, touch, field

I wrote my custom ObjectChoiceField. 
In order to stretch the full width of ComboBox screen.
The class is presented below:

```
public class ComboBox extends ObjectChoiceField {
    private final int PADDING_HEIGHT = 20;
    private final int width;
    private final int height;

    public ComboBox(Object[] choices, int width) {
        super("", choices, 0, FIELD_LEFT);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = getFont().getHeight() + PADDING_HEIGHT;
        this.setMinimalWidth(width);
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    protected void layout(int w, int h) {
        setExtent(width, height);
    }

    public void getFocusRect(XYRect rect) {
        rect.set(getFont().getAdvance(getLabel()), 0, width, height);
    }

}
```

It is works on simulator 9700, but does not work on 9800. I see throws next stacktrace:

```
C3CD62E3320B498 time: Wed Mar 23 15:10:29 2011  severity:1 type:3 app:Java Exception data:
    IllegalArgumentException
    No detail message
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Graphics
     <private>
     0x2726
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Graphics
     tileRop
     0x1C92
    net_rim_cldc-19(4C48DD41)
     BitmapBackground
     draw
     0xC4F
    net_rim_cldc-16(4C48DD41)
     ChoiceBox
     draw
     0x42AE
    net_rim_cldc-16(4C48DD41)
     ChoiceField
     paint
     0x55B0
    net_rim_cldc-12(4C48DD41)
     Field
     paintSelf
     0x6CF5
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paintChild
     0x7040
    net_rim_cldc-19(4C48DD41)
     VerticalFieldManager
     subpaint
     0xC6F0
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     <private>
     0x91C8
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paint
     0x7BA3
    net_rim_cldc-12(4C48DD41)
     Field
     paintSelf
     0x6CF5
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paintSelf
     0x7C14
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paintChild
     0x7040
    net_rim_cldc-19(4C48DD41)
     VerticalFieldManager
     subpaint
     0xC6F0
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     <private>
     0x91C8
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paint
     0x7BA3
    net_rim_cldc-12(4C48DD41)
     Field
     paintSelf
     0x6CF5
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paintSelf
     0x7C14
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paintChild
     0x7040
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     subpaint
     0x72C2
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     <private>
     0x91C8
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paint
     0x7BA3
    net_rim_cldc-12(4C48DD41)
     Field
     paintSelf
     0x6CF5
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paintSelf
     0x7C14
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paintChild
     0x7040
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     subpaint
     0x72C2
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     <private>
     0x91C8
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paint
     0x7BA3
    net_rim_cldc-12(4C48DD41)
     Field
     paintSelf
     0x6CF5
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paintSelf
     0x7C14
    net_rim_cldc-13(4C48DD41)
     Manager
     paintChild
     0x7040
    net_rim_cldc-14(4C48DD41)
     Screen
     paint
     0x3725
    net_rim_cldc-12(4C48DD41)
     Field
     paintSelf
     0x
```

Perhaps this is due to the fact that I use to build the project bb tools...
Do you have ideas how to fix?

Comment: I don't see your ComboBox in the stack trace.

Comment: What emulator do you use? I'm using to build the bb-tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call super.layout(w,h) from your layout method, so the ObjectChoiceField can set its internal state correctly.  After super.layout, you can then make any adjustments you need.

Answer (score -1):

layout is causing the problem. If you remove it, it works.

Maybe you can set width but I am not sure for height.